# What prevents CA private key from being calculated based on CA public key?

Tags: ssl, certificate, rsa, signature, verification

In RSA you basically have two primes for decryption and product for encryption. Normally you make decryption key private and and encryption public, however for CA signature verification the roles are reversed - CA encrypts the signature and browser decrypts it, so the decryption key is public. This means that the two primes are public, and once they are known everybody can multiply them together and get their dirty hands on the super-secret CA private key. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2):

> Normally you make decryption key private and and encryption public,  however for CA signature verification the roles are reversed - CA encrypts the signature and browser decrypts it, so the decryption key is public.

The signature is done on the server side by using the private key only known to the server. The signature is validated by the client using the public key. This means only the public key is public and the private key stays secret at the server.

This means that your assumption that both primes are public is wrong.

Answer (score 2):

> CA encrypts the signature and browser decrypts it, so the decryption key is public

No, the CA *signs* the message with the private key; and others can *verify* the message using the public key.

> What am I missing here?

The confusion probably comes from the way that many people learn how signing works, specifically because they learn about RSA as "encryption" is `m^e % n` and "decryption" is `m^d % n`. Then you learn that "signing" is a proof-of-private-key, done by `m^d % n` and "verification" is done by doing `m^e % n` and comparing the expected result to the digest of the message.  Conclusion: signing == decryption.

The reason you get taught that is because RSA is a hard algorithm to work out on paper (and even hard to write correctly for the computer) if you are using "sensible" payload sizes (that is, any size big enough to hold even an MD5 hash (128 bits), which would require a minimum key size of 216-bit, resulting in doing ModExp with `5.26e64 < d < 1.06e65`)

For RSA encryption (PKCS#1 v1.5 padding) you take your original message bytes and prepend them with

- 0x00
- 0x02
- (n.Length - m.Length - 3) random non-zero values (minimum 8 of these)
- 0x00

So encryption is actually `(00 02 padding 00 m)^e % n`; or more generically `pad(m)^e % n` (another encryption padding option, OAEP, works very differently).  Decryption now reverses that, and becomes `depad(m^d % n)`.

Signing, on the other hand, uses different padding:

1. Compute `T = DER-Encode(SEQUENCE(hashAlgorithmIdentifier, hash(m)))`
2. Construct

- 0x00
- 0x01
- (n.Length - T.Length - 3) zero-valued padding bytes
- 0x00
- T

Again, the more generic form is just `pad(m)^d % n`.  (RSA signatures have a second padding mode, called PSS, which is quite different)

Now signature verification deviates.  The formula is `verify(m^e % n)`.  The simplest, most correct, form of verify for PKCS#1 signature padding (RSASSA-PKCS1-v1_5) is:

- Run the signing padding formula again.
- Verify that all the bytes are the same as what was produced as the output of the public key operation.

PSS verification is very different.  PSS padding a) adds randomness that PKCS#1-signature padding doesn't have, and b) has a verify formula that only reveals "correct" or "not correct" without revealing what the expected message hash should be.

So the private key was always `(n, d)` and the public key was always `(n, e)`.  And signing and decrypting aren't really the same thing (but they both involve "the private key operation").  (The private key can also be considered the triplet `(p, q, e)`, or the quintuple `(p, q, dp, dq, qInv)`, but let's keep things simple :))

For more information see [RFC 8017](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8017), the most recent version of the RSA specification (which includes OAEP and PSS, as well as PKCS#1 encryption and PKCS#1 signature).

Answer (score 1):

> Normally you make decryption key private and and encryption public, however for CA signature verification the roles are reversed - CA encrypts the signature and browser decrypts it, so the decryption key is public.

No. The signature is signed with the private key and verified with the public key. There is no role reversal of the keys as far as privacy is concerned. If there was, the digital signature would be worthless, instead of legally binding.

> This means that the two primes are public

No it doesn't.

> What am I missing here?

Most of it.

Comment: okay you are saying that the product is public, this is the key for encryption, not decryption. How do you verify signature content with encryption key? You need a decryption key to open signature.

Answer (score 0):

CA works as a trusted authority to handle digital certificates. In RSA digital signature, you have the private key to sign and the public key to verify the signature. Your browsers have the public keys of all the major CAs.The browser uses this public key to verify the digital certificate of the web server signed by a trusted CA. So the private key is not public and you can't compromise it. You can do a simple google search to get a clear understanding of CA and digital certificates.